# adding and printing elements of ** pointer that is controlled by a pointer to a struct

Tags: c, dynamic, allocation

I have a struct typedef to SmartArray that has a variable char **array. I have been trying to debug the code for several hours, and have made lots of progress. However, i'm stuck on this particular bug. I have a function to print said array out. It will print twice, and then on the third time it does not print at all! I have a feeling this has something to do with how I am adding malloc to an array being one one does not print out correct.  For the last section of the array, it prints "Testing Na". Any ideas? I would appreciate the help.

Here is the part of the function I am suspecting is the cause, however, I can't seem to find it:   //allocate min space for string

```
  printf("approaching malloc\n");
  strPtr = malloc( sizeof(char) * (strlen(str) + 1) );

  if(strPtr == NULL)
  {
    return NULL;
  }
  printf("made it past malloc!\n");
  strcpy(strPtr, str);
  //if crash probably this code
  smarty->array[index] = strPtr;

  if(smarty->array[0] == NULL)
  {
    return NULL;
  }



  return strPtr;
```

Here is my test code:

```
typedef struct SmartArray
{
    // We will store an array of strings (i.e., an array of char arrays)
    char **array;

    // Size of array (i.e., number of elements that have been added to the array)
    int size;

    // Length of the array (i.e., the array's current maximum capacity)
    int capacity;

} SmartArray;
        int main(void)
    {
        int i; char buffer[32];

        SmartArray *smarty1 = createSmartArray(-1);
        printf("Array created\n");

            // Print the contents of smarty1.
            printf("\n-- SMART ARRAY 1: --\n");
            printSmartArray(smarty1);
            printf("Made it past print!\n");
            put(smarty1,"Hi, my name is ");
            put(smarty1, "Hello, my name is");
            put(smarty1, "Testing Names");
            printf("made it past put!\n");
            printf("smart away is now\n");
            printSmartArray(smarty1);
            printf("end of main!\n");
```

I feel like it's something completely obvious I'm just overlooking because I am a novice.

Here's a picture of what i'm trying to get it to look like in memory:
[click here for memory diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTl0v.jpg)

UPDATE: I figured out why it wasn't printing all the names, but the program segfaults atfter the print function.

Comment: There is no 2D array in your code. Neither is there an `int **`. Note that something like `int **` is not a 2D array and cannot point to one! It is a pointer to pointer, which is a completely different datatype than an array of arrays And read [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Olaf I have added it to my code.

Comment: Do you normally shout at the user?

Comment: @Ed Heal No, I just happened to have the caps locks on for my debug statements. I was hoping that I could remove them immediately, but hours later I still have had no luck with debugging it.

Comment: How is the `printf` or `put` bit is in lover case but stuff in quotes is in CAPS

Comment: As I wrote: you don't have a 2D array and nothing which can be used as one. And you should read the links  provided and follow the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is because you are trying to extend your array using `malloc`. A C array can only point to one block of storage at a time. When you use `malloc` it will allocate an entirely new block of storage and you are trying to add that on to the end of your array when you write `smarty->array[index] = strPtr`.

If you want to extend the size of your C array, use [`realloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) instead which will allocate a new, bigger block of memory for your array and copy the existing content to it as well.

If that doesn't solve the problem can you post your entire `put` function?

Comment: I could if I had to, however, it is an assignment that is due tomorrow night so if possible I would prefer not to post the whole thing. If necessary, I will.  Will the realloc make the pointer have a 2D section? The assignment is to create a 2D character "SmartArray" that dynamically allocates itself. I have added a picture above. Realloc, to me, sounds like it creates changes the memory address entirely. I'm confused.

Comment: Realloc lets you dynamically expand an existing array. So if you start with an array that is 5 elements long and then call realloc, you could make it 10 items long. The contents of the array is copied across to the new array as well. So the location of your first array will change, but all the pointers in it that point to your actual strings will be the same.

Comment: A segfault occurs because you are trying to access memory that you're not meant to be accessing. It could be because the index variable in your put function is out of range of your array. Have you properly allocated the array property of your SmartArray structure?

Comment: That's not ans answer, but a comment. Don't only comment in an answer.

Comment: Thank you, I had size declared to 10 so the loop was going around 10 times when it should've only went 3! It was trying to access a null pointer.